# How to graph and determine a function validity

Tags: functions, relations

why $ Y^4 = 8x^2 $ is not a function ? 
and what does the graph of this relation look like ?
I couldn't draw its graph in  desmoms online graph calculator.  https://www.desmos.com/calculator

Comment: The fact that it's not a function, follows from the fact that a unique value of $x$ does not give a unique value of $y$. For example, $x=1$ could give $y = 2\sqrt 2$ or $y = -2\sqrt 2$ and yet satisfy the equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $y^4 - 8x^2 = (y^2 - 2\sqrt2 x)(y^2 + 2\sqrt2 x)$. So if $y^4 = 8x^2$ then either $y^2 = 2\sqrt2 x$ or $y^2 = - 2\sqrt2 x$. That should help you plot it by hand. Or, you can let [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=implicitplot%5By%5E4%20-%208*x%5E2%20%3D%3D0,%20%7Bx,-4,4%7D,%20%7By,-4,4%7D%5D) do the job for you.

It's obvious from the plot that this is not a function, because each value of $x$ (except $x=0$) has **two** corresponding values of $y$.

Comment: great explanation , what do you call  $ (y^2 - 2\sqrt2 x)(y^2 + 2\sqrt2 x) $ ?

Comment: From an algebra point of view, it's a factorization of $y^4-8x^2$. From a graphical point of view, it's a pair of parabolas.